# Tabulator: How to create multiple tables?

Tags: javascript, tabulator

Hi I'm new to using tabulator. can someone help me add additional table to my code below. when i try to add another element.table2 on below it does not read. Hoping can someone guide me on where to place and declare the new table. I just started to code recently and all inputs are greatly appreciated

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">

<link href="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables/dist/css/tabulator_bootstrap5.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@5.4.4/dist/js/tabulator.min.js"></script>
<style>
.tabulator{
  font-size: 12px;
}   

</style>

  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
    <label>Search by Name</label><input type="text" id="search">
    </div> 
    <div id="data-table" class="data-table"></div>
    <div id="new-table" class="new-table"></div>
    <div id="alerts"></div>
   <script>

    const elements ={}
     
     document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",pageLoad)
     
     function pageLoad(){
      elements.alerts = document.getElementById("alerts")
      elements.search = document.getElementById("search")
      elements.search.addEventListener("input",searchData)
      
      loadData()
      
     }
     
     function loadData(){
      google.script.run
      .withSuccessHandler((jsData) =>{
          elements.table = new Tabulator("#data-table", {
          height:"50%", 
            data:jsData, //assign data to table
          pagination:"local",
          paginationSize:15,
          paginationSizeSelector:[ 10, 15, 20],
            layout:"fitColumns", //fit columns to width of table (optional)
            columns:[ //Define Table Columns
          {title:"Control No.", field:"ControlNo", width:150},
          {title:"Complete Name", field:"Complete Name", editor:"input", width:250},
          {title:"Company",editor:"input",field:"Company", width:175},
          {title:"NBI", field:"NBI Clearance",formatter:"link",width:100,formatterParams:{target:"_blank",label: "View NBI"}},
          {title:"Status", field:"STATUS 1",editor:"list", editorParams:{values:["Approved", "Rejected"]}, width:150},
          {title:"Date Approved", field:"Date Approved", width:150},
          {title:"Email Address", field:"Email Address of Contractor", width:150},
          ],
});


      elements.table.on("cellEdited", function(cell){
        //cell - cell component
        const controlNo = cell._cell.row.data.ControlNo
        const val = cell._cell.value 
        const field = cell._cell.column.field
        console.log(cell._cell)

        if(["STATUS 1","Complete Name","Company","Email Address of Contractor"].includes(field)){
        elements.alerts.textContent = "Saving Changes...."
        google.script.run
       .withSuccessHandler(()=>{
          elements.alerts.textContent = "Changes Saved!"
          clearAlerts(elements.alerts)
       })
        .withFailureHandler((er) =>{
          elements.alerts.textContent = "Error Saving Changes!"
           clearAlerts(elements.alerts)
        })
       .editCell({controlNo: controlNo, val: val, field: field})

       } 
       
      });

      })

      .withFailureHandler((er) =>{
      })
      .getData()
     }

      function clearAlerts(el){
        setTimeout(() =>{
          el.textContent = ""

        },2500)
      }
    function searchData(e){
     elements.table.setFilter("Complete Name", "like", e.target.value);
     } 
    
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Add addtional table by using tabulator.